# How do you start coding real projects and adding different languages together, once you learn the basics?

Tags: coding-style

So I have some basic syntax under my belt including php, jquery and mysql to name a few. I wanted to to start developing my code and I've read a few things around how to start writing your own code considering best practices and those are:

- Write a FAQ before coding
- Create a mindmap of all the different sections of the site and how they tie into a specific role of a user i.e. An admin, visitor, registered user, etc...

**Questions:**

1) I wanted to know what is best way to start when venturing off to coding a project? *(I'm getting mixed messages when I read how some developers suggest you start from the ground up while other suggest adopting other peoples code and framework to get a head start.)* What is your take on this?

2) How do you learn to tie different languages together, i.e. you have a membership script coded but you want to add some jquery for notifications...adding php and jquery together? *(I realize this might be too vague of a question, I just want a premise to how one goes about learning to tie compatible languages together)*

Comment: This is a discussion request, and isn't appropriate for StackOverflow. The [help] pages have information regarding the types of questions that you should (and should not) ask here. Good luck.

Comment: I feel I wasn't trying to debate, but merely get an idea of how a beginner with syntax education should go about diving in. I don't want a discussion of theory, but reality....like as Enno said about time vs. results. You could of been more specific in your request by giving an example how my form of communicating in this particular case, came across as a discussion request. Your reply was a generic non-productive reply.

Comment: I didn't say "debate". I said "discuss", which is specifically mentioned as off-topic here. Your question is asking for opinion and advice, which is not specific. @Enno was wrong to have answered an off-topic question here (see my comment to that answer). As I said, see the [help] - it clearly states what is and isn't appropriate here. You should familiarize yourself with those guidelines if you're going to ask questions here (and that is constructive advice). Also, I'm not required to explain a close or downvote here; I did so as a courtesy for your benefit. Constructive criticism is good. :)

Comment: Well "debate" is a form of discussion...putting trying to be funny aside...my goal at the end of the day was to put two questions in one setting, I see now that this place is built on more specific questions that don't cause a long paged discussion of various answers...You have to agree though, that even on a specific question there are 10 different ways to fix or code something, one will say do this and the other says no do that...I don't want to ask 5 different small questions separately that eventually tie into each other for me at the end of the day, that is a waste of time.

Comment: Thank you by the way for the constructive link, I read between the lines for the constructive criticism you wanted to portray, as I didn't see it bluntly written out related to my form of writing these questions above.

Comment: I could say it bluntly, but then you'd probably think it wasn't constructive. :-) While there might be 10 different ways to do something in code, those are actually something that can be judged on merit. Personal opinion about "How do I best learn something?" are a different matter. Read your own words: "how do you start coding real projects" and "what is best way to start when venturing off to coding a project?" are not quantifiable, and 10 different ways to code something accompanied by actual source code are quite easily evaluated. I'm not sure where they're not distinctly different.

Comment: More bluntly, though: If I ask "What's the best way to learn how to drive?", what's the specific answer? Would it be "Take lessons"? Or "get behind the wheel and try"? Or "drive what exactly - a mule, or a generator, or a car?". What is the **specific** answer to that question that can be judged as being **correct**? What question (and answer) will be useful to future users of this site? (SO isn't for solving your specific problem now - it's a repository of knowledge for others. Your question needs to be helpful to them too.)

Comment: "I could say it bluntly, but then you'd probably think it wasn't constructive."....an assumption of it's own, however I appreciate the valuable insight in your two answers combined, guidelines that help bring more targeted questions with more specific answers. I would like to say though I did do some research beforehand trying to find the answer I was looking for to my question, but I couldn't find it. Your comments above were duely noted... :)

Comment: Well, I see you want to turn this into a discussion as well, so I'll say this, you can reply and have the last word. :-) You said yourself that my first comment was a "generic, non-productive reply" (when I specifically cited a reason and link) and "I read between the lines...as I didn't see it bluntly written out". "Here's a link to why your request for a discussion of a non-specific topic is not appropriate here" seems fairly clear, but you judged it "generic" and "non-productive". If a specific citation is "non-productive", how is thinking bluntness will be less well received wrong? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly point out, it's not easy at all to go from basic syntax to a project. Even trivial projects have lots of different domains that you have to care about. Security, performance, testability, flexibility etc. etc. It is pretty much impossible to have enough knowledge to make adequate judgement on all these domains when you start off.

This is why you should adopt other people's code and frameworks. Sure, coding a small aspect of technology domain from "scratch" can be a good training, but if you tried to develop "everything" from scratch you'll never get very far (just imagine how many years it will take you to code a decent HTTP server and a DB driver).

My recommendation would be to start with tutorials and sample code. Indeed, even senior developers usually start their project from tutorials and sample projects, or stuff they've written in the past. **Be open to change, but always value past successful experiences, be it your own or of other people**. This is the golden rule of software development.

This approach also lets you learn how to tie different technologies cleanly without making your life unnecessarily painful.

Comment: This question is off-topic according to the guidelines here (it's a discussion/opinion question). [Shouid I answer off-topic questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133552/172661)